# Moving ffmpeg from root to user/local

Tags: ffmpeg

I noticed that when I followed a guide to install ffmpeg (some time ago), that all of the scripts i want to use, say that ffmpeg need to be in the /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg mine is in root, how do I move the folder to the correct location without messing anything up? My server is centos 6.5

Comment: How do you install things? When building from source, use the `--prefix` option. If it's the default package manager, why would you want it somewhere else (since I assume the package manager has a good reason to install it where it does).

Comment: Note that this may be better asked at [ServerFault](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: look,

Some of you need to remember that some of us are new to this stuff and we may not word everything correctly, yes ffmpeg was compiled, agin I followed a tutorial. I am trying to setup my centos/red5 server for streaming and according to a few tutorials I have installed xuggler and ffmpeg. The videowhisper vod rquest to use ffmpeg in the file location stated in my question. This is not the first time I have run into this problem. So, I just want to put it in the correct place.

Comment: You didn't mention which guide you followed.

Comment: Then "videowhisper vod" (whatever it is) is incorrect: it should just use `ffmpeg` as found in your `PATH`, or provide its own `ffmpeg` version.

Comment: Ok, lets try this another way, can youor anybody helpme to resolve this problem? I am simply trying to make it work. I cannot change the path in videowhisper app because it has no save button for that screen, using as wordpress plugin. The functions is to allow video upload and converting. I am not trying to argue with you.

Comment: If you are "simply trying to make it work", then copy `ffmpeg` to its new place and be done with it. We're asking these question, because guides may be wrong, and it's a bad idea to just randomly move stuff around. If videowhisper tells you it needs `ffmpeg`, then you should tell videowhisper where to find it, not let videowhisper tell you where to put it.

Comment: Note that all this has nothing to do with programming, but (since you're setting up a server), [SuperUser[(http://superuser.com/) could help you better.